# Use os.walk to sort files then run a function only on the first file in the folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

I want to be able to walk a root folder with two subfolders in it, go to either of those subfolders, sort the files and then run a separate function on only the first of the sorted files, then do the same thing in the remaining folder.  Here is my code so far, and it does not work.  The `AppendFiles` function never runs, and when I put a traceback at the end of this section it doesn't give me any errors.

```
x=0
y=0
errorFiles={}
datadir = 'C:/root/path'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(datadir):
    for dirname in dirs:
        for filename in sorted(files, key=int):
            name = filename[:-4]
            file = datetime.strptime(name, "%y%m%d%H")
            (x,errorFiles) = AppendFiles(file,datadir,dirname,x,y,errorFiles)
            if x==0:
                pass
            else:
                print("The following" + dirname + " files experienced a Decoding Error:\n")
                for i in range(x):
                    print(errorFiles[i] + "\n")
                break
```

The `name = filename[:-4]` part is just to strip the filenames of the `.csv` at the end so it will play nice with my function.  I'm not sure where to go from here, any and all help appreciated!

Side question, is my syntax correct at the `(x,errorFiles)` line?  `AppendFiles()` returns `(a,b)` where `b` is an array.

Comment: `os.walk` returns a 3-tuple. The first member is the current directory and it will only be returned once for each walked directory.

Answer (score 5):

**Main Answer:**

The (partial) docs for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) (emphasis mine):

> os.walk(top, . . .)
>
> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), **it yields a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`**.
>
> **`dirpath` is a string, the path to the directory**.
>
> **`dirnames` is a list of the names of the subdirectories in `dirpath`** (excluding '.' and '..').
>
> **`filenames` is a list of the names of the non-directory files in `dirpath`**.
>
> Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).

So, your first line should read

```
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(datadir):
```

and below that you do not want to iterate over the files for each dir, because the files are for `dirname`, not the dirs -- they'll get their turn on the next iterations.

An example might help.  If you had this:

```
./
|-- a.txt
|-- b.text
|-- .swp
|
|-- mno/
|  |-- f
|  |-- k
|  `-- p
`-- xyz/
   |-- e
   |-- h
   `-- w
```

then `os.walk('.')` would return:

```
dirname  |      dirs        |          files
---------+------------------+-----------------------------
'.'      |  ['xyz', 'mno']  |  ['b.text', 'a.txt', '.swp']
'./xyz'  |  []              |  ['h', 'e', 'w']
'./mno'  |  []              |  ['k', 'f', 'p']
```

`os.walk()` is not the right tool for what you are trying to do -- it goes through every child directory (and its children, and its children's children, ...) and for each child directory it finds it returns:

- the name of the current child, relative to the initial path passed in
- a list of all the directories in that child
- a list of all the files in that child

Walking through your code with my example data:

```
datadir = '.'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(datadir):
    # root = '.'
    # dirs = ['mno', 'xyz']
    # files = ['a.txt', 'b.text', '.swp']
    #
    for dirname in dirs:
        # dirname = 'mno'
        for filename in sorted(files, key=int):
            # filename = '.swp'
```

and the rest is irrelevant, as hopefully you can see that `filename` (aka `'.swp'`) is not one of the files living in `dirname` (aka `'mno'`).

---

You know you have two subfolders, so just `os.listdir()` them and work on the returned files, which will be the files in that folder.

---

**Side Answer:**

> Is my syntax correct at the `(x,errorFiles)` line? `AppendFiles()` returns `(a,b)` where `b` is an array.

Yes, this syntax is correct -- although the `()`s around `x, errorFiles` are unnecessary and you could write:

```
x, errorFiles = AppendFiles(file, datadir, dirname, x, y, errorFiles)
```

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing how this helps me.  I feel more confused, I think.  So I DON'T want to iterate over the files for each dir...because...why?  I have a root directory (datadir) with 2 subdirectories.  For each subdirectory, I need to sort the files and pass only the first file name to a variable.  I then need to strip it of the .csv and make it a datetime object, and pass THAT and the name of the folder it is in to my function...  How do I do that?  Just iterate over the dirs only, you're saying?

Comment: Oooh, Thank you very much for the clarification.  I can see now what you were saying.  I will just use os.listdir() as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be done in **one line**.

```
{root: sorted(files, key=func)[0] for root, _, files in os.walk(top) if files}
```

About the `key` function `func`

```
def func(filename):
    return something
# something that can be used for comparison
# You are using int() constructor for func(). Can the filename be converted to int? 
# in that case it has to contain only numbers like "23456".
```

Read the doc for `os.walk()`. It **does not** return what you seem to think it does.

Comment: So if I use this, it just replaces the 3 for lines I guess?  And all the other stuff would go under it, with `filename` being replaced by `files`?  Also, my files are all numbers aside from the .csv at the end.  Would `key=int` still work?

Comment: If your files are like `"1234.csv"` then `func:= lambda x: int(x.rstrip(".csv"))`. Thats about it . You will get `{dir1: file1, dir2: file2,...}`. Kindly give a up vote if it works.

Comment: Will do, still trying to make it work though.  I'm not sure what `func:= lambda x: int(x.rstrip(".csv"))` means.  Sorry, I'm pretty new to this.  Do I define like `def func(filename):  labmda x: int(x.rstrip(".csv"))`?  Also still not quite sure on the syntax after your one line as compared to my code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant  `sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(x.rstrip(".csv")))`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort.  I'm going with a slightly different way, but this part has help a lot.